# Question about limit point

Tags: general-topology

I have this set $A=\lbrace (-1)^n(1+\frac1n), n\in \mathbb{N}\rbrace$ and i m looking for the limit point of $A$, i take $u_n= (-1)^n(1+\frac1n)$ and i found that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}u_{2n}=1$ and $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}u_{2n+1}=-1$

What i must say $\overline{A}=\{-1,1\}$ or $\overline{A}=A\cup \{-1,1\}$ ?

Thank you.

Comment: The second one if $\bar{A}$ denotes closure of $A$.

Comment: can we say that for sequences limit points are the same as the values of the closure ?

Answer (score 0):

$\overline{A}=A\cup A'$, where $A'$ is the set of all limit points of $A$.

So, $\overline{A}=A\cup \{-1,1\}$ is correct.

Comment: can we say that for sequences limit points are the same as the values of the closure ?

Comment: @Vrouvrou: I don't think so. The limit points are the limits of the sequence but remember that the closure is the union of both the set of limit points and the set itself, so although the closure contains the limit points of the sequence, it is not necessarily the case that all points of the closure are limit points.